# print sequence of number by java

Tags: java

I have for loop without printed value , I should put the value which will print in this for loop :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
   out.print(_________+" ");
}
```

The sequence should print :   57   46   35   24   13   2   -9   -20
**Any help for solve this**

Comment: Start with 57 and subtract 11 each time.

Comment: Yes, I recognized that after writing my comment

Comment: I should use the same for loop and only can add value to print

Comment: Please post the logic , instead of posting the print statement . it would be helpful for other developers to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequence should start with 57 and go down by 11 until -20 (if I am right).

So, just start the loop with 57, use >=20 as condition and execute -=11 every time:

```
for(int i=57;i>=20;i-=11){
    out.print(i+" ");
}
```

In the loop body, i (that changes acvording to your sequence) and a space is being printed every time.

If you want to use the same loop, you can do this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    out.print(68-11*i+" ");
}
```

This calculates the sequence values by taking the next higher value (than the first value) and substracted 11 for the first time, 22 for the second time etc.

Comment: I should use the same for loop and only can add value to print

Comment: I added this to my answer.

Comment: I got it and it's worked for me , Thanks

Comment: I would appreciate you accepting my answer, then.